# PostGIS-Geography doesn't show in QGIS after database restore

Tags: qgis, postgis, geography-data-type

I recently restored a PostgreSQL database from a SQL dump. It worked well insofar as all my tables and data are restored. However, one of the original tables contained a PostGIS geography column containing points, which I could load into QGIS. This layer used to be indicated with a points symbol in the DB-Manager in QGIS, now it is shown as a normal table (see below), although in the field list of the DB-Manager it is correctly shown as a geography column.

[image]

I can load this table into QGIS, where it also only shows up as a table layer without a geometry, although the *geography* column is in the attribute table (see below).

[image]

I can export the layer as a CSV and when reimporting it, the geography column is automatically selected and the geometries are loaded correctly. So this would be a workaround, but this should not be way to do it. Is this a bug, or is there something I can do about it?

I am currently using PostgreSQL 12.6 and QGIS 3.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, tables with geography behave that way, when loaded from DB Manager into the canvas with with 'right click' > 'add to canvas'

Chosing a different approach within QGIS will lead to the expected result, though:

1. Drag and drop from the browser into the canvas
2. Use the dialog from the top menu 'Layer' > 'Add Layer' > 'Add PostGis Layers...'